# Why won't this Scheme function compile?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have this scheme function that I'm supposed to run lists of integers on but I have no idea what the error means. The error states: "if: expected a question and two answers, but found 4 parts in: (if(null? list) '() (cons (+ 1 (car list)) (f(cdr list)))). What is missing from this function and what on earth does '() do? Thanks! I've never used Scheme before.

```
(define (f list)
    (if (null? list)
        ’()
        (cons (+ 1 (car list)) (f (cdr list)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character you are using to quote the empty list is the right quotation mark `’`, U+2019. Your code works fine if you use the ascii apostrophe `'`, U+0027

```
(define (f list)
    (if (null? list)
        '()
        (cons (+ 1 (car list)) (f (cdr list)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You used the wrong quote (maybe a copy paste error?).

Use  `'`   not `’`.